Qt6 Undefined reference to `vtable for [my class here]` on Windows Clion
I have been trying for a few days to get to Qt and I'm honestly having a lot of troubles, even putting files in directories/compiling it is pretty mysterious to me...
I am currently facing a problem where whenever I try to compile I will get this undefined reference for some reason.
The cmakelists should be correct, it looks something like that:
set(SOURCES
    all the source files


set(UI_FILES
    all the ui files
)

qt6_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS ${UI_FILES})

include_directories(
    all the directories with a .hpp in them
)

add_executable(Project WIN32
        ${SOURCES}
        ${UI_FILES}
        ${UI_HEADERS}
)

target_link_libraries(Project PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)


Honestly, I tried everything I could think of/find on the net.
The file tree is pretty basic, I got a dir for src(source files), include(all the include files) and a gui(for the ui files). Each of the directories has subdirectories that correspond to the different aspects of the projects (cpp files for the qt are in a different subDir that ones working on the backend).
When putting the .ui file in the gui dir, I even used set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui) to specify where to look for it and target_include_directories(Project PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui) and I would still get that undefined reference.
Literally the only way I have to make it compile and run is to put the .cpp, .hpp and .ui files in the same subdirectory and add all that to the set(SOURCES) which is like the absolute grossest way to do that in my opinion.
edit: Here's the error I get
FAILED: MonkeyModelKit.exe 
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Albert\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin\g++.exe -g -mwindows CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/MonkeyModelKit_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/StringManipulation.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/run/MonkeyShell.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/run/MonkeyManager.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/run/MonkeyFile.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/col/MonkeyModel.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/col/MonkeySession.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/col/MonkeyCollection.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/gui/MonkeyWindow.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/res/ico/mmk.rc.obj -o MonkeyModelKit.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libMonkeyModelKit.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/libQt6Widgets.a  C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/libQt6Gui.a  C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/libQt6Core.a  -lmpr  -luserenv  -lmingw32  C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/libQt6EntryPoint.a  -lshell32  -ld3d11  -ldxgi  -ldxguid  -ld3d12  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Users\Albert\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/MonkeyModelKit.dir/src/gui/MonkeyWindow.cpp.obj:MonkeyWindow.c:(.rdata$.refptr._ZTV12MonkeyWindow[.refptr._ZTV12MonkeyWindow]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for MonkeyWindow'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

edit 2: Here's the MonkeyWindow.cpp class and everything defined:
MonkeyWindow::MonkeyWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MonkeyWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MonkeyWindow::~MonkeyWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MonkeyWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MonkeyWindow : public QMainWindow {
Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MonkeyWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MonkeyWindow() override;

private:
    Ui::MonkeyWindow *ui;
};

edit3: added the CMakeLists as per requested in the comments
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(MonkeyModelKit LANGUAGES CXX)

# Find the Qt libraries
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        REQUIRED)

# Set the source files for your application
set(SOURCES
        src/main.cpp
        src/StringManipulation.cpp

        src/run/MonkeyShell.cpp
        src/run/MonkeyManager.cpp
        src/run/MonkeyFile.cpp

        src/col/MonkeyModel.cpp
        src/col/MonkeySession.cpp
        src/col/MonkeyCollection.cpp

        src/gui/MonkeyWindow.cpp
        # Add more source files as needed
)

# Set the user interface files (if any)
set(UI_FILES
        gui/MonkeyWindow.ui
        # Add more UI files as needed
)

# Generate header files from UI files
qt6_wrap_ui(UI_HEADERS ${UI_FILES})

# Set up the translation files
set(TS_FILES
        # Add translation files if needed
)

include_directories(
        include/
        include/col
        include/run
        include/gui
        /gui
)

# Add the executable target
add_executable(MonkeyModelKit WIN32
        ${SOURCES}
        ${UI_FILES}
        ${UI_HEADERS}
        ${QM_FILES}
)

target_include_directories(MonkeyModelKit
        PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gui
)

# Link the Qt libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(MonkeyModelKit PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)

Any help appreciated...

It would help if you supplied the actual error. Undefined reference to what? The issue is most likely that you're missing files in the build process.

The actual error is pretty long, I'll edit it in the post in 1 sec.

The class MonkeyWindow is missing some definition. Please show a [mre]

@AlanBirtles I have added the code of the class (both cpp and hpp files) in the edit 2, I have changed nothing to Clion's template. Is it normal tho that when all the files are in the same sub-dir everything works just fine ? Both compiling and running it ?

still not a [mre], show your actual cmake file

@AlanBirtles Added in edit 3, sorry, I dont necessarily know how to make a minimal reproducible example since this does not properly regards code, every code that there is has been given in edit 2, and the only thing that differs when it works is where the files are placed..

I haven't used Qt6, but shouldn't there be a moc_monkeywindow.cpp that's generated, which I am not seeing in the build command. I tend to use CMake's AutoMoc variable instead.
